# How to fix Newsletter in Mac os X mail and gmaile

Tags: css, macos, gmail, alignment, newsletter

I have created Newsletter Template in Magento CMS, perfectly it has been aligned in Mac OS X mail, but in g-mail it is not aligned properly. I go through N number of post but no luck. Please support(guide) me with a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

This might be because Gmail strips the **head** tag from emails. Inlining your CSS will assure gmail users to view the email properly.
https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/gmail-no-head/
Campaign Monitors inliner is quite good: http://inliner.cm/